# Why is my filter for an array returning an empty list when there should be multiple matching items

Tags: arrays, react-native, filter, supabase-database

My data is stored in two separate tables; "posts" and "profiles". Each `User` object comes from the "profiles" table but also has a list `posts` which is not a column in "profiles". Because of this, I need to fetch the posts first, then their corresponding users, then add each post to their `User` object based on "uid". My function below works for most of that but every user has an empty `posts` list, even when there should be posts.

```
  const [posts, setPosts] = useState<Array<Post>>([]);
  const [profiles, setProfiles] = useState<Array<User>>([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    async function fetchData() {
      const { data: postsData } = await supabase.from("posts").select("*");

      const postUids = postsData!.map((post) => post.uid);

      const { data: profilesData } = await supabase
        .from("profiles")
        .select("*")
        .in("uid", postUids);

      setPosts(postsData!.map((post) => new Post(post)));
      const profiles = profilesData!.map((userData: any) => {
        const userPosts: Array<Post> = posts.filter(
          (post) => post.uid === userData.uid
        );
        console.log("User posts: " + userPosts);
        const user = new User({ ...userData, posts: userPosts });
        // user.posts = [...user.posts, ...userPosts];
        console.log(user);
        return user;
      });
      setProfiles((prevUsers) => [...prevUsers, ...profiles]);
      console.log(profiles);
    }

    fetchData();
  }, []);

  console.log(posts);
  console.log(profiles);
```

Example of postsData:

```
[{
   "caption":"Caption",
   "date":"1669244422569",
   "imageUrls":[
      "https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2020/05/04/16/05/mckenzie-river-5129717__480.jpg"
   ],
   "location":{
      "latitude":150,
      "locationInfo":"City, State",
      "longitude":-150
   },
   "postId":"1669244407166",
   "uid":"daf6b8be-7cd0-4341-89d7-07879b207087"
}]
```

Post object:

```
export default class Post {
  imageUrls: Array<string>;
  postId: string;
  uid: string;
  caption: string;
  location: Location;
  date: number;

  constructor(post: any) {
    this.imageUrls = post.imageUrls;
    this.postId = post.postId;
    this.uid = post.uid;
    this.caption = post.caption;
    this.location = post.location;
    this.date = post.date;
  }
}
```

Example of profilesData:

```
{
   "blockedUsers":[],
   "displayName":"name",
"photoURL":"https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2020/05/04/16/05/mckenzie-river-5129717__480.jpg",
   "uid":"daf6b8be-7cd0-4341-89d7-07879b207087",
   "verified":false
}
```

User object:

```
export default class User {
  uid: string;
  blockedUsers: Array<string>;
  posts: Array<Post>;
  photoURL: string;
  displayName: string;
  verified: boolean;

  constructor(user: any) {
    this.uid = user.uid;
    this.blockedUsers = user.blockedUsers;
    this.posts = user.posts;
    this.photoURL = user.photoURL;
    this.displayName = user.displayName;
    this.verified = user.verified;
  }
}
```

Comment: Please add test data

Comment: I added some example data and the object classes.

Comment: Set a breakpoint in the line you do the `posts.filter` and check if `posts` really contain the elements you expect ...

Comment: I have done that, it logs as nothing. I think that there is something wrong with my `posts.filter` function because the posts and users do log as expected separately.

Comment: You are calling `setPosts` before you do the `posts.filter`.This seems to be a State modifier from react. If that's the case, this operation is async, thus at `posts.filter` your `posts` may not contain the items you are expecting....

Comment: If that's really your data structure, your `filter` is fine, but the problem is in the data ...

Comment: Well, my example data is exactly what was logged, just with the values replaced... that is why I'm confused.

Comment: Yes, I am using `useState`, I just added a bit more of the surrounding code for more context. The two logs at the end are what I would expect, the only issue is that each user object has an empty posts array.

Comment: As I said: set a *breakpoint* (not console.log) at your `posts.filter` and check if your data is there in the browsers developer tools. `console.log` can be misleading, especially in asynchronous code

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/251825/discussion-between-globe-and-derpirscher).

Answer (score 1):

Not entirely sure why you are not getting any posts data, might be due to how your RLS is configured, but there is a better way to query your data.

You can query `posts` and `profiles` at the same time like this:

```js
const { data, error } = await supabase.from("profiles").select("*, posts(*)");
```

This way, you don't have to do another query to retrieve the profiles separately, and you also don't have to loop through the retrieved objects to modify them.

Comment: Interesting. How would I use this data? One reason that I am using a separate query for `posts` is that I also have a separate Array for all of the posts.

Comment: @Globe
What exactly do you mean by "How would I use this data?"? The data returned in my response contains the profiles as an array, and in each of those profiles, it will contain an array of posts. Without knowing the full nature of your app, I'm not entirely sure how you might use it, but it essentially contains what you have as `profiles` at the end of your two queries and the loop.